# The right way to do html imports with Polymer elements?

Tags: polymer, web-component

Say, I have element A and B. The imports in B are:

```
<!-- Imports in B -->
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../another-element/another-element.html">
```

Now I want to use B in A. What is the "right" way to import B? Should A just import B like this?

```
<!-- Imports in A: Method 1 -->
<link rel="import" href="../element-b/element-b.html">
```

Or should A also import all the imports used by B like the following?

```
<!-- Imports in A: Method 2 -->
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../another-element/another-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../element-b/element-b.html">
```

If Google's own Polymer Elements can be of any guidance, the answer appears to be Method 2, i.e. importing all dependent htmls. But if that is the case, the "import" syntax in Polymer/WebComponents seems to break encapsulation for no obvious reason. For example, here is the "paper-dropdown-menu" element from Polymer:

https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu/blob/master/paper-dropdown-menu.html

It imports "paper-input.html", which has its own imports:

https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/master/paper-input.html

The following 2 imports are used in both elements:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../iron-form-element-behavior/iron-form-element-behavior.html">
```

If paper-dropdown-menu.html already imports paper-input.html, why does paper-dropdown-menu have to import polymer.html and iron-form-element again? The problem with this is that the imports can get out of control very quickly when composing an app with many elements. Yes, I know Vulcanize. But I don't see how that helps the development process when one is creating or using an element. In addition, encapsulation means A shouldn't need to know the internal parts of B in the example above. Or is Polymer/Webcomponent really saying that html imports in a component are part of the "public interface" of that component?

Comment: It seems that import will be removed in march 2018:  Is the plan to remove `HTML imports entirely? Yes - but ... plan is still unclear ... Blink is the only engine that implements HTML imports, and no other browsers
are likely to implement it.  So HTML imports will get into a dead-end some time in the future` ([source](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/VZraFwqnp9Y/discussion)). Also see [polymer imports deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632987/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import the elements you directly depend on. You can ignore transitive dependencies because they are imported in the elements you import directly anyway.
In addition each element should import `<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">`.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 is the "***better***" way. Each polymer element is supposed to bundle its own dependencies, so it can function by itself when used.

Method 2 isn't that good, you will be re-importing the imports of element B twice, thats a waste of bandwidth especially when you aren't using a function (like polymers inbuilt importHref) that checks if an element has already been imported before fetching it again.