# Polymer HTML Imports Deprecated

Tags: html, polymer

So I've just got started with polymer and got this message:

```
[Deprecation] Styling master document from stylesheets defined in HTML Imports 
is deprecated, and is planned to be removed in M65, around March 2018. Please 
refer to ....... for possible migration paths.
```

After doing some reading it seems to be that

```
<link rel="import" href="/SOR/bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
```

Was causing the issue and rel=import for html was being deprecated. Is this right? If so what is the fix, how should I be doing this?

Cheers

Comment: Polymer version? Have you updated paper-input to the latest version of the Polymer's major release you are using?

Comment: This is the other issue I'm having when I install elements I keep getting asked for polymer version - I think there's about 8 different ones and I'm not sure which to choose.

Comment: Simply run `bower update` to keep all your elements up to date! You only need to worry about which major release you are using (Polymer 1.x or Polymer 2.x) and leave the rest to bower update & bower.json to handle.

Comment: Cheers I'll give it a go

Comment: The best fix is actually to port your project to Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has actually been solved by the polymer team, as described on their [blog](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2017-10-18-upcoming-changes.html)

So versions 1.10.1 or newer for 1.x and 2.1.1 or newer for 2.x are ok, however the warning doesn't go away (see blog entry for more details).

I also tested a polymer 2.6 app on Chromium 65 and on chrome 67 beta and it works fine everywhere :)

Answer (score 5):

So, according to the new version of chrome (61.xx.x). Google has made a decision that `Styling master document from stylesheets defined in HTML Imports`
is not a good approach and so it will be unable to do in future chrome versions.

Because of this, we have to upgrade to version 2.x

Well, nothing much interesting except that Google has made a decision that **HTML imports** will be **removed** in future.  This is much more frustrating. Everyone who is using Polymer 1.x or 2.x will have to update their projects to newer version of polymer (at least 3.x). Unfortunately version 3.x has no support in all major browsers (except Chrome, but not fully). So we can only hope that the remove of HTML imports will not be soon.

For me this is really piece of s**t. I have many projects written in Polymer and I am not able to upgrade them. (there is no time for this) even i had time, I don't have trust in Google Polymer... Their support is 0. They don't even answer  to bugs. Old versions are already stopped from updating. No long-term support versions.

official discussion: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/VZraFwqnp9Y/discussion

Comment: Cheers for your help - I see why they're removing it, I just feel it lacks a replacement. Though to be honest I could live without but enjoy using polymer.

Comment: So long as you don't upgrade your version of Polymer, you should be good. Polymer provides a polyfill for HTML imports, which is why it works in non-Blink browsers.

HTML imports was a first crack at standardizing resource loading and since it won't be supported by evergreen browsers going forward, it's being deprecated.

Polymer 3.x should be using the ES Module loader, so if you do want to upgrade, look into that.

Comment: Thanks for comment @MarkKimitch. We all know how slow polyfills are. Its nearly impossible to use application written in Polymer on IE .. loads take like 10 times more time. So if this happen in chrome, nobody will want to visit these sites. Of course Polymer 3.x is using newest features. But as said from the official report: there is not even one browser that supports dynamic imports. Which means, Polymer 3.x isn't usable at this moment and it's also waste of time to learn it since everything can change

Comment: downvote because the polyfill will take care of imports. the html imports polyfill is not that bad, and will keep your projects running until you can standardize them to es modules.

Comment: @BennyPowers downvote for such a thing? really? Have you ever used polyfill on Polymer? Well it is so slow that it is nearly imposible to use it in these days where everyone expect site to be loaded in less than a second. Which is with polyfills really hard to make. So please, consider your downvote

Comment: The shadow dom polyfill and the html imports polyfill are not the same thing. We gained standard modules at the price of html imports and the complaining about the churn that an automatic tool called modulizer will handle for you, if you decide for some reason not to rely on the polyfill. Whining on SO about it will not help speed standards adoption.

Comment: @BennyPowers we are still getting to the same thing. You have to invest your time to make it work.. this is still the main thing i was complaining about. I can't use modulizer tool since I have specific builds in my projects. + I am not using shadow dom, because back in days when there was still no Polymer 2.0 it was easier to use shady dom. And when I started to write projects in Polymer 1.0 I expected some stability and reliability. And i don't need to mention that even Polymer 2.0 will be deprecated. So what should we do now when we just want to once write a project and let it be as it is

Comment: I feel your pain. It took quite a while to move my app to class elements, but that's the new standard. As early adopters, we should have been prepared. The difference between this and angular churn is that now we have a standard which ships baked into iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Polymer it's worth remembering that webcomponents.js is actually a polyfill. We currently run Polymer version 0.5 and this can actually be tested by starting your current Chrome with those features disabled. On Mac you can do this quitting Chrome and then run from command line:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0,CustomElementsV0,HTMLImports
```

Polymer 0.5 applies the Polyfill when these features are disabled.

Here is the documentation on running Chrome in debug mode [Chromium debug flags](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags)

Comment: Cheers thanks, it hasn't been a problem since we've migrated to polymer 3 using npm but that debug trick is really handy so cheers for letting me know.